# CKfinder is always displaying blank screen when trying to use browse server option

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using ckeditor/ckfinder in my application to update the xml files content. While the update of xml content is working fine in this project, the browse server functionality is not working.

When I click on the browse server functionality it only display empty page.
Tried to set the baseurl and baseDir attribute for the image file but still it is giving the same blank screen.

What can be the reason behind this?

[image]

Comment: Could you see console for any errors? Both in main window and in popup window.

Comment: I tried it both in firefox and ie but not giving any type of error

Comment: Have you tried: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Troubleshooting?

Comment: I go through it but didn't find solution to this issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell you ckeditor where to find ckfinder for the browsing capabilities :
Try something like that:

CKFinder.setupCKEditor();

It looks for CKEditor instances to set it up your current loaded CKFinder

Answer (score 0):

I've got some of problems with ckeditor, with mvc.net.

Not sure, you use it or using asp.net.

I give you code i use, and it's running, now :

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('html_content_editor');
CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, '/Scripts/ckfinder/');

where html_content_editor is the id of my html text control
and '/Scripts/ckfinder' is the url of the content of all files and directories use for ckfinder.

And pay attention about setting in web.config.

In app.setting node, you have to use : 
**`<add key="CKEditor.Directory.Path" value="D:\Tmps\Documents\" />`**